# What character is depicted in the Heroes of the Storm Mage Wars Brawl portrait?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Who is the character portrayed in the portrait awarded for participating in three Mage Wars brawls in Heroes of the Storm?

[image: Heroes of the Storm - Mage Wars Brawl portrait award]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is not a named character, but the [minion-wizard](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Minion) from Heroes of the Storm. The clothes and colors closely match, as well as the beard. The presence of the scroll roll on the back is also fairly unique.

Reference image below, with the minion in the center.

[image]

Comment: Agreed - looking at the rest of the brawl portraits [here](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Portrait#Heroes_Brawl_Portraits), they appear to be related to the brawl, and not Heroes.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I'd agree except that both the *Hammer Time* and *Ghost Protcol* brawls awarded Hero portraits. That said, both heroes were the star of those particular brawls.